# Error with no line number Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptionProvider in module System.dll

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

Having an working Univeral solution written in Visual Studio 2013 C#/XAML for WP 8.1 and Windows Store 8.1. Following pretty much Jerry Nixon and Daren may's MVA "Developing Universal Windows Apps with C# and XAML" best practices.

I'm now all of a sudden getting this not trackable compiling error "Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptionProvider in module System.dll". It only affects WP8.1 and not the Windows Store app which still compiles and runs.

What to do or looking for?

/Leon

Comment: did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JSON.Net (Newtonsoft.JSON) NuGet package in your solution? I had a similar error being thrown. If you are using it, just uninstall it and then install it again. Works like a charm.

Comment: I'm sorry. That didn't help. Still same error w/ JSON uninstalled and dependencies managed...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove any references in your project related to System.ComponentModel (and add again if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

The project has a bad reference.  Look under References and see if one looks out of place.  I had this happen when Intellisense inserted a reference & 'using' statement for an unknown type and they were invalid for the project type.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue anymore w/ VS 2017.